# How can I split a column at two sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table boat with the columns and attributes bellow.

```
+-----+--------+-------------+
| bid | bname  | color       |
+-----+--------+-------------+
|  88 | Sophie | Blue        |
|  17 | Kate   | Light Green |
|  13 | Peter  | Yellow      |
|   1 | Nicola | Red         |
|  72 | Christ | Red         |
|  19 | Rick   | Light Green |
|  77 | Morty  | Blue        |
+-----+--------+--------+----+
```

How can I print a table that match boats names with same color like:

```
+--------+--------+
| boat1  | boat2  |
+--------+--------+
| Sophie | Morty  |
| Kate   | Rick   |
| Nicola | Christ |
+--------+--------+
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: There happen to be two boats of the same color at most. What if there are three or more?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with self-join, here is the [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Tav1G8YH6Js1BCctZjhZ7/0)

```
select 
    a.bname as boat1,
    b.bname as boat2
from myTable a
join myTable b
on a.color = b.color
where a.bid > b.bid
and a.bname != b.bname
```

Comment: Why `GROUP BY`? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Yes. Remove group by

Answer (score -1):

Only two boats per color:

```
select color, min(bname) as boat1, max(bname) as boat2
from boat
group by color
having count(*) > 1
order by color;
```

All boats per color, two per row:

```
select b1.color, b1.bname as boat1, b2.bname as boat2
from boat b1
join boat b2 on b2.bname > b1.bname and b2.color = b1.color
order by b1.color;
```

All boats per color in one row:

```
select color, string_agg(bname, ', ' order by bname) as boats
from boat
group by color
having count(*) > 1
order by color;
```

Comment: @Himanshu Ahuja: I don't understand what you are asking. My answer shows that this kind of problem is usually solved with aggregation where the queries differ slightly for only two boats and an unknown number of boats (for in the latter case we can no longer show the boats in separate columns). A self-join is an alternative, but has the disadvantage of showing all pairs separately and hence some boats again and again when there are multiple matches. Does this answer your question?